# Tail call optimization is not working in babel ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Just implemented the tail calls sample code in Node.js which will be translated by using babel (enabled the ES2015 Syntax support), but it just throws the exception `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

```
//index.js
require('babel-core/register');
require('./sample.js');

//sample.js
function factorial(n, acc = 1) {
    'use strict';
    if (n <= 1) return acc;
    return factorial(n - 1, n * acc);
}

// Stack overflow in most implementations today,
// // but safe on arbitrary inputs in ES6
factorial(100000)
```

Here is my babel depens.

```
├─┬ babel-core@6.2.1
│ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.1.18
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
│ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ detect-indent@3.0.1
│ │ │ ├── get-stdin@4.0.1
│ │ │ └── minimist@1.2.0
│ │ ├── is-integer@1.0.6
│ │ └── trim-right@1.0.1
│ ├── babel-helpers@6.1.20
│ ├── babel-messages@6.2.1
│ ├─┬ babel-register@6.2.0
│ │ ├── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ ├─┬ home-or-tmp@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── os-tmpdir@1.0.1
│ │ │ └── user-home@1.1.1
│ │ └─┬ source-map-support@0.2.10
│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.32
│ │     └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ ├── babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ ├── babel-template@6.2.0
│ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.2.0
│ │ ├── globals@8.12.1
│ │ └─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │   └── loose-envify@1.1.0
│ ├─┬ babel-types@6.2.0
│ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├── babylon@6.2.0
│ ├── convert-source-map@1.1.2
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── json5@0.4.0
│ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ ├─┬ minimatch@2.0.10
│ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.1
│ │   ├── balanced-match@0.2.1
│ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
│ ├── path-exists@1.0.0
│ ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.0
│ ├── private@0.1.6
│ ├── shebang-regex@1.0.0
│ ├── slash@1.0.0
│ └── source-map@0.5.3
└─┬ babel-preset-es2015@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.2.0
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.1.18
  ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.2.2
  │ ├── babel-helper-define-map@6.2.0
  │ ├── babel-helper-function-name@6.2.0
  │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.1.18
  │ └── babel-helper-replace-supers@6.2.0
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.1.18
  ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.2.0
  │ └── babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode@6.2.0
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.1.18
  ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.1.18
  │ ├─┬ babel-helper-call-delegate@6.2.0
  │ │ └── babel-helper-hoist-variables@6.1.18
  │ └── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.2.0
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.1.18
  ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.1.18
  │ └── babel-helper-regex@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.1.18
  ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.1.18
```

And one thing to prove I setup up my environment correctly is, the default parameter in a function did work in my babel project, but not in a pure nodejs environment. For example,

```
function  add(a, b=2) {
    console.log(a + b);
}
add(3); //In babel project this will output 5
//But it just threw an exception in pure nodejs file.(without require babel/register and setup the es2015 subset in .babelrc)
```

Here is my entry files.

However, if I try to implement other feature,such as template string or arrows function, they are all working correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run that code as it is? You have to run the translated code, not the original code. Template strings and arrow functions are supported natively by Node.js, without Babel.

Comment: What is it transpiled to? Are you confident it's even transpiled?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, I am sure about that because I used to try to write some spread expressions as function's parameters. And it worked.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra Yes, actually I have another file called `index.js` and it is the entry file of the project. At the top of this entry file, I require `babel-core/register`.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra Just noticed, arrow functions did support by nodejs 5.0, thx... But how about the spread expression?

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang Yes https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Comment: @PrashanthChandra Just right now, I implemented a pure nodejs file with default parameter, it threw an exception, but it will work in my babel project. So I think I did setup babel correctly.

Comment: I copy pasted your code into https://babeljs.io/repl/ and ran the translated code in node, it worked. Try that and see if it works. If not, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Post your index.js, especially the requires

Comment: @PrashanthChandra Just posted.

Comment: Possibly a bug with `babel-core` module. I tried `babel sample.js --preset es2015` and it shows you the transpiled code. It translated the spread operator correctly, but made no optimisations to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no environment yet that supports TCO. Babel used have an experimental TCO transform, but it was removed in v6.

Comment: So what if the environment doesn't support TCO? The code should still be transpiled to an optimised version that doesn't overflow the stack.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra: What makes you think so?

Comment: Because I was able to copy the above code, paste it into https://babeljs.io/repl/, run the output in node, and it doesn't overflow the stack.

Comment: The REPL still uses Babel v5. As I said, the TCO transform was removed in v6.

Comment: Could you provide a source? It's confusing because that code snippet was taken straight from v6 docs.

Comment: We're tracking the TODO to re-implement here: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2614

Comment: @Prashanth: Well, ES6 still has TCO, it's just not implemented. The note for partial support is outdated.